# Why is my image not centered in my DIV?

Tags: html, html5-video, center, centering

I've got to admit, I really don't much about HTML, but I'm attempting to learn. I have an image centered in a DIV, but it isn't truly centered horizontally. The left edge of it is where the center would be, like this:

[----------|----------]

[----------|image--]

[----------|----------]

What to do, what to do....

EDIT
Some code:

```
<style>
#Outer {
position:relative;
height:100%;
width:100%;
text-align: center;
}

#Picture {
position:fixed;
top: 30%;

}
</style>
```

Also, I am centering it vertically AND horizontally. Vertical is working just fine.

Comment: Can you post the code, HTML and CSS?

Comment: really need the code to see what needs done.

Comment: alright, i've added some code that may be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try changing position to relative. (see http://jsfiddle.net/VLCqz/1/)

As for the reason why...

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons for this, please post your html and css code to get a better answer.

Something that should work is setting the `parent text-align` property to `center` in the css. ([see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KK4K6/))

Answer (score 0):

I'm only learning html too but i have found that using something like

```
#picture
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

will get the div or whatever the style is for to be in the middle of the parent div

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Set a width on the image and then set the margin on the image to be 0px auto.

```
<!-- Your HTML -->
<img src="path_to_image.jpg" alt="set alternate text" id="img_id" />

/* Your CSS: */
#img_id {
width: set the width of the image in pixels here (i.e. 250px);
margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do it like this. :)

```
<div style="margin:auto;">
      <img src="" id="" />
</div>
```